# SQL INSERT INTO FROM SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database created on Microsoft SQL Server 2012, I have two tables "dbo.Products" and "dbo.Categories". I am trying to query these two tables to create a PRODUCT dimension table for a star schema.

```
Products {ProductID, ProductName, SupplierID, CategoryID, QuantityPerUnit, UnitPrice, UnitsInStock, UnitsOnOrder, ReorderLevel, Discontinued}
Categories {CategoryID, CategoryName, Description}
```

*These two tables are from the Northwind database*

The Product Dimension contains a product_key, productID, productName, categoryID, categoryName and categoryDescription which are queried from the Northwind Products/Categories tables.

The SQL code I am using is here:

```
/*Create Dimension Table */
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PRODUCT] (
[product_key] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL Primary Key,
[productID] [int] NULL ,
[productName] nvarchar(30) NULL ,
[categoryID] [int] NULL ,
[categoryName] nvarchar(30) NULL ,
[categoryDescription] nvarchar(30) NULL 
) 

/* Populate (insert) Dimension Table with a select statement that joins 
Product and Categories. */
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PRODUCT] (productID, productName, categoryID, categoryName, categoryDescription)
   SELECT 
      ProductID, ProductName, CategoryID, CategoryName, CategoryDescription
   FROM 
      Products 
   INNER JOIN 
      Categories ON Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID;
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: You need to use two part name in your select to resolve the name ambiguity, I can see one column name for sure `CategoryID` there may be more.

Comment: My question has to do with the syntax in the SELECT statement, I've tried using two part names by using [dbo].[Products] but I get "Invalid object name".

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO [acs4904_a1].[dbo].[PRODUCT] 
(productID, productName, categoryID, categoryName, categoryDescription)

SELECT 
P.ProductID, 
P.ProductName, 
C.CategoryID, 
C.CategoryName, 
C.CategoryDescription
FROM [acs4904_a1].[dbo].Products P 
INNER JOIN [acs4904_a1].[dbo].Categories C ON P.CategoryID=C.CategoryID;
```

Comment: It's throwing an error because "northwind.dbo.Categories" is an invalid object name. MSSQL Server Mgmt Studio can't seem to find the Products and Categories table because of my syntax.

Comment: Do you see northwind database in your list of database? Can you post screenshot of your database list? Also make sure the user you are running as has access to Northwind database

Comment: A screenshot can be found here: http://i.imgur.com/CI4ANqC.png
I have my northwind tables and my other tables for the star schema in the same database for these purposes. The UPPERCASE tables are part of the star schema that I am working on.

Comment: your database name is acs4904_a1, i updated my query, try now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to scope the shared columns.

```
INSERT INTO [PRODUCT] (productID, productName, categoryID, categoryName, categoryDescription)
SELECT ProductID, ProductName, Products.CategoryID, CategoryName, CategoryDescription
FROM Products 
INNER JOIN Categories ON Categories.CategoryID=Products.CategoryID;
```